# Священный, желанный

Tags: прилагательные, причастия, суффиксы

Почему эти и другие подобные слова пишутся с двумя "н"? В уч. литературе они подаются как исключения. Чем вызвано их исключительное положение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-нн-или-н- зависит от вида,а в русском языке есть двувидовые глаголы:1) старые русские и старославянские глаголы (их около 60) различного морфемного строения, например: велЕть, женИть, казнИть, обещАть, наследОВАть, мОлвить, рАнить,сочетАть; 2) заимствованные основы, оформленные русским суффиксом -ОВА-с иноязычными наращениями ^ -ИЗОВА-; -ИРОВА-; -ИЗИРОВА-; -ФИЦИРОВА-. Примеры: рекомендовать, ревизовать, игнорировать, систематизировать, газифицировать. Это глаголы 3-его продуктивного класса. Современные толковые словари фиксируют более 600 таких глаголов без учёта терминологической и узкоспециальной лексики
лимитировать, транслировать, активизировать, стабилизировать, исследовать, использовать, организовать и под.).
 Иногда трудно определить вид глагола, поэтому принимают решение писать единообразно формы, образованные от двувидовых глаголов: ранить - раненый с одной -н- в отличие от причастия раненный кем-то, а вот этот список отглагольных прилагательных, образованных от страдательных причастий несовершенного вида, образованных от двувидовых глаголов и употребляемых в значении сов. вида, с двумя -нн-

Священный - от святить,( например, я свящу - свячу куличи),и сов., и несов. вид- святить - придать однократно и придавать многократно  святость, потом слово переосмыслилось, приобрело переносный смысл, а напоминание о возможности употребить его в сов.виде - написание -нн-(свящённый кем-то однократно, а ё в церковных  словах не было, значит священный)

Желанный - от желать в значении "пожелать, возжелать" - тоже в переносном значении приобрёло значение сов.вида, от глагола однократного действия "желать кого-то" - "желанный кем-то".

Потому и дают эти слова для запоминания, что современные значения отличны от первоначальных и нам не понять, что они от глаголов сов. вида.Нужно подставлять слова "кем-то".

Comment: А почему здесь написано, что *желанный* образовано от гл. несов. в.? http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=1992

Answer (score 1):

При выборе Н/НН в отглагольных формах (прилагательных и причастиях)  используется формальное правило 4-х признаков, но значительное количество  слов в это правило не укладывается и считается исключениями. Для их объяснения следует определить вид суффиксов и их значение. Для образования отглагольных прилагательных  используется один из 4-х суффиксов: Н, НН, ЕН, ЕНН, а для образования причастий только НН и ЕНН.

Суффиксы Н/ЕН используются при образовании прилагательных, обозначающих результат действия.Эти прилагательные  составляют пару прилагательное-причастие, как указывается в правилах 4-х признаков: крашеный - недавно крашенный, званый - званный к обеду.

Суффиксы НН/ЕНН  (при отсутствии 4-х признаков) используются для образования   прилагательных со значением  ОБЩЕГО ОТНОШЕНИЯ к действию, а не РЕЗУЛЬТАТА действия (эти прилагательные не имеют парных причастий): нежданный, негаданный,  неслыханный, невиданный,  нечаянный, отчаянный, медленный,  священный,  деланный, беспрестанный, действенный.

В другой группе отглагольных прилагательных с двумя буквами НН отсутствует глагольный суффикс (поэтому они не могут быть причастиями), удвоение НН происходит на стыке морфем, как и для отыменных прилагательных. Суффикс Н имеет значение признака или свойства, отнесенного к действию:  чеканить – чеканный, бранить – бранный, чваниться – чванный, жеманиться – жеманный.